# How to paste text that had been copied (alt-w) prior to my latest paste (ctrl-y)?

Tags: copy-paste

Once I have selected some text I use `Alt-w` to copy the region and then use `ctrl-y` to paste it. Is there a way to paste something I have selected and copied with `Alt-w` prior to my latest paste?

Comment: Try `C-y M-y`, repeating `M-y` as many times as you have to.

Comment: See also `undo-tree` mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After yanking with `C-y`, press `M-y` to run the command `yank-pop`. Repeated presses will cycle through the `kill-ring`.

For example, if you have:

```
Hello, world!
```

and you kill `Hello` and `world` (you have `, !` left), then go to the next line and hit:

<kbd>C-y</kbd> `world`

<kbd>M-y</kbd> `Hello`

<kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd> `Hello Hello`

<kbd>C--</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd> `Hello world`

Comment: when I press `M-y` it says previous command was not a yank

Comment: @Vass Yes, you'll have to run the command `yank` (`C-y`), then press `M-y` to cycle through.

Comment: I select text and then press C-y and it gets pasted on the spot

Comment: After it gets pasted on the spot, use `M-y` to *replace* it with the previous bit of copied text. See the Emacs manual, node [**Yanking**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Yanking.html).

Comment: @Vass I don't understand what you mean. `C-y` runs the command `yank`, which is analogous to the concept of "pasting". Each time you kill text, or copy it with `C-w` (`kill-ring-save`), it gets pushed to the `kill-ring`. When you hit `C-y`, this pops the first element of the `kill-ring` and inserts it into the buffer. Subsequent presses of `M-y` (`kill-ring-pop`) will cycle through the elements saved in the `kill-ring`.

Comment: @nanny, but when I use C-w, the text is 'cut'/'removed' I just want to copy it the fist time. I use the M-w or  Alt-w to copy.

Comment: @Vass, oops, that is a typo on my part. It should have read `M-w`. The command is right, though.

Answer (score 3):

@nanny has given you the answer. And if `M-y` says that the previous command was not a yank then you probably forgot to do `C-y` first.  IOW, you first do `C-y` to yank the latest kill, which is not what you want. Then you do `M-y` to get the previous one instead. You can repeat `M-y` to cycle backward.

See the Emacs manual, node [**Yanking**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Yanking.html) for general information about copying and pasting, and the `kill-ring`.

---

Anyway, I wanted to mention the [**secondary selection**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection). In particular, it can be very handy in situations where you might otherwise want to use `C-y M-y`.

The secondary selection is just what it says: a second selection, unrelated to the selection that is the region in Emacs. It stays available regardless of whether the region is active, and its position is not affected by point or mark.

If you use library [**`second-sel.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection#secondary-sel.el) then you get many of the advantages of the `kill-ring` (which is for the region) for the secondary selection as well.  It adds the secondary selection to a second selection ring, `secondary-selection-ring`, which is similar to, but separate from, the `kill-ring`. It also prevents the secondary selection from being added to the `kill-ring`, so you now have two separate selection-history rings.

`M-y` then cycles items from the appropriate ring, depending on whether it follows a yank of the primary (region) or pasting of the secondary selection.

Comment: so I don't use Alt-w to copy? I have to kill it?

Comment: No, you can use `M-w` (Alt-w, if you will) to copy. If you do `C-h k M-w` you will see that `M-w` is bound to `kill-ring-save`, and you will see what that command does - it copies the region to the `kill-ring`. The bits of text that are in the `kill-ring` are called "kills", whether they got there by killing text or copying text (e.g. using `M-w`).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is `helm-show-kill-ring`.  I used Helm for quite a while before I even realized this existed.  I have it bound to `M-y`.  It makes it very fast and easy to see existing entries, narrow them down, and choose the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

After you paste, `M-y` will replace the pasted text with previously copied text.

If you press `M-y` multiple times then you can cycle through all your previously copied (or cut/killed) text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily **see** previously pieces of copied and killed text, and choose one or more such pieces, these can help:

- [**Browse Kill Ring**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BrowseKillRing) - Browse the `kill-ring` to choose a kill to yank. That page shows several alternative libraries that offer this behavior in different ways. The main one is [`browse-kill-ring.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/browse-kill-ring.el).
- [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) -

  - **`M-y`**: Yank from either the `kill-ring` or the `secondary-selection-ring`, depending on the last yank type (you need library [`second-sel.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/second-sel.el) for the second alternative). If the last command was not a yank then this is the same as `C-- C-y` (see next).
  - **`C-- C-y`** (`C-y` with a negative prefix arg): Lets you choose any number of kills to insert using completion.  During completion you can use:

    - `C-,` to sort the candidates to yank in different ways (repeat)
    - `S-delete` to remove a candidate entry from the selection ring
    - `C-S-return` to copy a candidate to the other selection ring
- [**Helm**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Helm) - See @bluejay's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10379/105) on this page.